# Grunt.js only watches on change of root js file, not working on change of css or jade files

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using `grunt.js` - to watch the changes on my project and reload the browser. In which it's only considering the `js` file change on `root` folder. In case if i change on `stylesheet/styles.css` - not refreshing the browser, same thing happening with `jade` filest too..

How can i make `grunt` to refresh the page on change of `jade` file or any other noted files?

here is my grunt.js:

```
 module.exports = function(grunt) {
     // Project configuration.
     grunt.initConfig({
         watch: {
             all: {
                 options: {
                     livereload: true
                 },
                 files : ['*.js','puplic/stylesheet/*.css', '*.html', '/views/*.jade']
//only on js changes refresh the page!
             }
         }

     });
     // Each plugin must be loaded following this pattern
     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
     grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

 }
```

here is my jade file:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheet/bootstrap.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheet/styles.css')
        script(src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js")
    body
        div.container
            h1 Welcome to Social!
```

Any one help me go sort this issue please?

Comment: It seems to work for jade `views/*.jade`

Comment: Did you notice that you spelled "public" wrong in your files array?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my grunt file like this, it works fine for me!

```
 module.exports = function(grunt) {
     // Project configuration.
     grunt.initConfig({
         watch: {
             all: {
                 options: {
                     livereload: true
                 },
                 files: ['**/*']
             }
         }

     });
     // Each plugin must be loaded following this pattern
     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
     grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

 }
```

Thanks to all...